# Please help me understand what's wrong with my code

Tags: php

This is my php code.

```
<?php
function monthlyBonus($n){
$bonus = ($n * (567/987)) /2 ;
reurn "Your bonus is = ". $bonus ;
}
echo monthlyBonus('7893');
?>
```

I don't understand why it's showing an error.

Comment: use `return` not `reurn`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typographical error

```
*return* "Your bonus is = ". $bonus;
```

Answer (score 1):

Syntax error? you mistyped **`return`**

```
<?php
function monthlyBonus($n){
  $bonus = ($n * (567/987)) /2 ;
  return "Your bonus is = ". $bonus ;
}
echo value('7893');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error, it should be `return` not `reurn`. 
Also you should send the number as an integer not string, i.e `monthlyBonus(7893)` instead of `monthlyBonus('7893')`.

Comment: `monthlyBonus(7893) instead of monthlyBonus('7893').` is not exactly.

Comment: @DoNhuVy Yes, PHP is loosely typed, so monthlyBonus('7893') might still work, but it is not a good practice. Also in PHP7 static types are returning, so it is always good to follow proper variable type to avoid hassles.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.variables.intro.php I don't see what you called `good practice` yet.

Comment: Not currently, but in new PHP7 release. See: http://blog.pascal-martin.fr/post/in-favor-of-rfc-scalar-type-hints.html , http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2015/02/scalar-types-and-php.html  & the official RFC https://wiki.php.net/rfc/scalar_type_hints also the latest RFC which is implemented for PHP7 https://wiki.php.net/rfc/scalar_type_hints_v5

Answer (score 0):

`reurn` must be `return`. Also try to use  `monthlyBonus(7893)` (integer parameter instead of string).

Comment: `integer parameter instead of string` ?